# Dell PowerEdge Maximum Disk Size

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2900 server which I am trying to setup as a NAS. I have not done any firmware upgrades to the RAID controller or anything like that. What I need to know is what the maximum disk size is with the standard backplace firmware. I am wanting to slot 4TB drives in but not sure if the backplane will support 4TB drives.

Comment: What RAID controller it uses? An S6/i or similar?

Comment: Yeah, S6/i if memory serves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From this "Verified Answer"](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19412446) by DELL, the S6/i only supports 2 TB-sized disks at most.